# How to rename this multiple folder using CMD / command line

Tags: powershell, cmd, command-line

[image: See picture here]

I want to rename the folder to the last 8 digit character. I want to remove all in-front character, just leave 8 digit. How can i do this in command line?

Comment: What is your plan in case this produces duplicate file names? `a file - 57603333` and `another file 57603333` would result in the same name.

Comment: @lit the 8 digit number on behind is unique number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
Get-ChildItem | ForEach-Object {$test = $_.Name.Split(" - "); Rename-Item -Path $_ -NewName $test[$test.Count - 1]}
```

Comment: can you give reference, that i can learn more about this